# power went off when merging two partitions

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

While merging two partitions the power went off. now the partitions are damaged. Is there any possible way to retrieve even some of the data if not all(no back-ups were made)?

Comment: You should always do a full-disc back-up before embarking on any partition work: I guess you will next time. There are a number of partition recovery tools, several free, but I cannot suggest any, since you have not said which OS you do or can use. Otherwise, you'll need to recover files from whatever back-ups you have.

Comment: @AFH I use both windows and linux.

Comment: I've had success with both Convar [PC Inspector](http://www.pcinspector.de/default.htm?language=1) on Windows and `testdisk` on Ubuntu. Both are free.

Comment: Photorec (part of Testdisk suite) will be able to pull raw files off the drive where those files are not fragmented - unfortunately without meaningful filenames though.  You should advise how you attempted to merge the partitions for better advice.

Comment: What was the file system on said partitions? This is crucial information.

Comment: No backup and no UPS?  That's really working without a net.